# Installation stops with a 500 error

Tags: install

I am getting the following error when installing craft .. do you have any clue of what I might be doing wrong or missing out?

[image: Craft error during installation]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to the database already having a particular table defined. Was not so easy to find, some type of error would have made my life easier.

Solution: Re-create the database. Re-run the installation process.